# How to accept call Agora from IOS VOIP background

Tags: swift, flutter, voip, agora.io

I have developed voice calling application using Agora , Flutter , Firebase notification and VOIP notification for IOS.

I use following package to display calling screen and i have registered push registry in AppDelegate.swift file.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("didReceiveIncomingPushWith")
        guard type == .voIP else { return }
        
        let id = payload.dictionaryPayload["id"] as? String ?? ""
        let nameCaller = payload.dictionaryPayload["nameCaller"] as? String ?? ""
        let handle = payload.dictionaryPayload["handle"] as? String ?? ""
        let isVideo = payload.dictionaryPayload["isVideo"] as? Bool ?? false
        
        let data = flutter_callkit_incoming.Data(id: id, nameCaller: nameCaller, handle: handle, type: isVideo ? 1 : 0)
        //set more data
        data.extra = payload.dictionaryPayload["extra"] as? NSDictionary ?? [:]
        
     print("Notification: ", "INCOMING")
        SwiftFlutterCallkitIncomingPlugin.sharedInstance?.showCallkitIncoming(data, fromPushKit: true)
}
```

I have received the VOIP call screen and when app is opened everything work fine but when app is in terminated state I receive the call but it won't connect with Agora call because its on flutter code and app is terminated.

Can I know a way to join the agora call when IOS app is in terminated state

Comment: You need to implement callkit in order to receive call in terminated or background state.

Comment: Yes I receive the call when terminated state but when I answer the call it dont open the agora connection, but call screen is showing ongoing call

Comment: @ndev Hi, I have also implemented calls functionality using agora and flutter_callkit_incoming but for some reason, I stop getting calls on iOS after a few minutes of terminating the app. Can you please help me with that?
I also tried implementing callkit but that didn't resolve this issue.

And on android, I am unable to get the call in terminated state unless I provide something in the notification field (which in turn gives me an empty notification with a call). Thanks

Comment: I have used Apple VOIP function to get notification on terminated state, its on their documentation https://github.com/hiennguyen92/flutter_callkit_incoming/blob/master/PUSHKIT.md

Comment: Hi, as I said I did that whole configuration but that didn't work as intended. is there a specific change needed in the cloud function's payload? Can you please share your payload for android and iOS? Thanks